# How to modify certain website features from browser on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, plugins

There are some annoying websites which use custom (badly made) cursors, right click disable/popup JS, etc.

How can I easily undo their settings without specifically finding this piece of JS on their JS files, and instead somehow tell my browser to enable for example the right click again?

I know Stylish probably could do that, but it requires me to update the files every time the website changes their files?

Edit: My Firefox version is 21.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox 23 removed the `disable javascript` options.

**Toggle Javascript**

You can install the [QuickJava](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjava) extension or [Toolbar Buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toolbar-buttons) extension to toggle js, css, images, etc. There is also [Tab Permissions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-permissions/) extension that allows changing these per tab.

---

**Block sites from disabling the right-click (context) menu**

Oh and apparently you can add the old Firefox options back using [SettingSanity](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/settingsanity/) extension. `Preferences -> Content -> JS Advanced -> uncheck all three options`.

*Note: SettingSanity not required for Firefox versions older than 23.0*

[image: disable javascript nonsense]

---

**Block sites from setting custom cursors**

1. Install the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) extension
2. `View -> Sidebar -> Stylish -> Write New Style`
3. **Name:** `Disable custom cursors`
4. **Textbox:**

   `* {cursor:auto !important}`

   `a, a * {cursor:pointer !important}`
5. `Save`

[image]

Note: If you don't want to use the browser built-in text cursor use
`* {cursor:default !important}` instead of **auto**.

This solution isn't perfect, ideally you would only disallow `* {cursor:url(ugly-cursor.png)}`

---

Adding these fixes to [JustBrowsing LiveCD](http://justbrowsing.info), so this is win-win, thank you for bringing my attention to this. Lastly, if you come across a site that manages to get around these blocks, please leave a comment with the link.

Comment: I dont want to disable all JS. thats the problem. im already a happy user of QuickJava. a lot of websites disable right click in hope of preventing "illegal copy of images", some of those are big news sites. cursor modification is rare, but annoying when it happens.

Comment: See the attached screenshot. You need to install the SettingSanity extension to restore those settings for Firefox 23 and above. If you uncheck the box `disable or replace context menus` (the context menu is the name for the right-click menu) then Firefox won't allow them to disable it.

Comment: "Not available for Firefox 21.0" :(

Comment: You don't need SettingSanity for Firefox 21.0. Just go to `Tools -> Settings` (Windows) or `Edit -> Preferences` (Linux) and select the **Content** tab. Next to *Enable JavaScript* is a button labeled **Advanced** then uncheck allow scripts to `move or resize popup windows`, `raise or lower windows` and `disable or replace context menus`.

Comment: Ah! Found it! thanks. i just realised that maybe Stylish could be used to disable the cursor changes too? not sure if it can make a global style file though?

Comment: Updated answer with Stylish CSS cursor blocking fix.

Comment: Nice! What is this so called "LiveCD" of yours ? EDIT: the cursor fix doesnt work :S if i move mouse on a link here, for example your nick, i see the Text cursor instead of hand.

Comment: Oops. The cursor fix still fails to work. For example on PHP BB. I have decided to disable it completely since i keep finding more and more websites where it doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work out. [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/noscript/) might also help you in some instances. Also [watch this similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/633268/how-to-prevent-javascript-on-web-site-messing-with-browser/).