# How to prevent JavaScript on web site messing with browser

Tags: browser, javascript

Is there any way to prevent specific JS scritps messing with browser (Firefox or Chrome)? For example some sites are blocking copy\paste functionality for input fields forcing user to type some text like an e-mail or password each time. And this is really annoying when you're working with sоme site which is asking password to do the simplest things each minute, especially annoying if you have a 25+ symbols in your password. 
Disabling Java Script at all is not an option since the same web site form can rely on Ajax or have some "dynamic" JS elements and without them page is not working properly.

Comment: On a side note, its probably more secure to have a simpler password you are happy to type, than a complicated one you need to copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291916/disabling-loading-specific-javascript-files-with-firefox

Several options with Firefox:

Use the Addon "Adblock Plus". It will probably still accesses the js but does not execute it.

Use the Addon "Greasemonkey", which - when cofigured right - does not even touch the js-url. But its generally harder to configure right. ;)

Have a look at Firefox's buildin security policies: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security_Policies Here you can block javascript on an url or even function-level

Answer (score 2):

As [oozic](https://superuser.com/users/246374/oozic) mentioned, you'll need to combine several techniques.

- Enable Firefox to disable right-click hijacking and use Stylish to override custom cursors: [How to modify certain website features from browser on Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/631708/how-to-modify-certain-website-features-from-browser-on-firefox)
- [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/noscript/) extension to selectively disable Javascript
- [Remember Passwords](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/remember-passwords/) extension to force allow Firefox's built-in password manager